# "rewrite" structure for subdomain on Nginx

Tags: nginx, mod-rewrite, subdomain, ispconfig

I want to do a custom `rewrite` for the subdomain on ISPconfig. When I add the code below for this, the subdomain is redirected to the main domain.

**Sample #1:**

```
server {
  ...
     if ($http_host = "panel.example.com") {
         rewrite ^(?!/(_SubDomains/Panel|stats|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /_SubDomains/Panel/$2 last;
         rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2? last;
      }
  ...
 }
```

If I do as in example two, Nginx server does not work.

**Sample #2:**

```
server {
...
     if ($http_host = "panel.example.com") {
         rewrite ^(?!/(_SubDomains/Panel|stats|\.well-known/acme-challenge))/(.*)$ /_SubDomains/Panel/$2 last;
         location ~ \.php$ {
                 rewrite ^/(.*)/(.*)$ /index.php?cmd=$1&scd=$2? last;
         }
     }
...
}
```

How can I do subdomain-specific rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

You should create separated server blocks for different subdomains:

```
server {
...
   server_name foo.example.com;
...
}

server {
...
   server_name bar.example.com;
...
}
```

Comment: Is this possible in ISPconfig, do you know?

Comment: Sure. See Method #2 on page https://docs.ispconfig.org/creating-web-sites/subdomains/

Comment: Thank you, I will check now